# Bounds on singular values of invertible 0-1 matrices

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, singular-values, 0-1-matrices

I'm interested in considering digraphs from an algebraic perspective, which leads me to the following question.

Consider an invertible 0-1 matrix of shape $n \times n$.

- What lower and upper bounds are known about its singular values?
- Are there any known results for the upper-triangular 0-1 special case, at least?

**N.B.** This question is cross-posted from [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3010956/439) (where it won me the coveted Tumbleweed Badge).

Comment: I'm not a specialist in matrix theory, so this may be wrong: would Smith Normal Form help? Many of the manipulations to get SNF are done by triangular matrices with determinant one. If so, check out Miodrag Zivkovic and his 2005 ArXiv submission on classification of small 0-1 matrices.  The values in the SNF depend greatly on the prime factorization of the determinant. Gerhard "It Is A Personal Favorite" Paseman, 2018.12.04

Comment: If you want to get something effortlessly, then looking at the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is usually a reasonable idea, and under your assumptions, this gives that $n\le \sum s_j^2 \le n(n-1)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: That's a nice idea for obtaining an tighter upper bound on the largest singular value (while leaving the question of a lower bound on the smallest singular value open). I think that we instead have $n \leqslant \sum s_j^2 \leqslant n^2 - (n-1)$, as the matrix $\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ seems to violate your upper bound.

Comment: No. SNF results in A=PNQ where P and Q are integer matrices with determinants of absolute value 1, and N is diagonal with each nonzero element dividing the next. For A with absolute determinant value a prime p, the SNF N is the identity except for the lower right entry which is p.  Gerhard "Sounds Quite Singular To Me" Paseman, 2018.12.05.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: Yes, your upper bound is correct (not mine), and in fact the observation I had in mind was that the matrix has to have at least $n-1$ zeros (or else two columns will be identical), which your bound expresses.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I've deleted my previous comment, but thanks for correcting me. Still, this seems to be doing a sort of violence to the information of the singular value decomposition. While the SNF will contain a list of integers, whose product is the same as the product of the singular values, the smallest singular value may be less than 1, and in some cases scales as $O(n^{-1})$. Do you see a way that I might nevertheless use the SNF to obtain a lower bound for the singular values?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the maximum singular value is at most $n$.  Moreover, for $n>1$ it is possible for $n-1$ to be a singular value (consider a matrix with diagonal entries $0$ and off-diagonal entries $1$), so this upper bound is not far from optimal.

The determinant of your matrix is an integer, so the product of singular values is at least $1$.  Since the maximum singular value is at most $n$, the minimum singular value is at least $n^{-(n+1)}$.  However, I don't expect that lower bound to be anywhere near optimal.

Comment: Let $J_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix of all $1$s, and $M_n = J_n - I_n$. As you say, the largest singular value of $M_n$ is $n-1$; all of the others are $1$. We can push this a bit further with $X_n = J_n - I_n + E_{1,1}$, which (it seems to me) has a largest singular value of  $\tfrac{1}{2}(\sqrt{(n-1)^2 + 4\,} + (n - 1))$. What is striking after some numerical experimentation is that, for $1 < n < 20$, the singular values apart from the largest and the smallest all seem to be 1, so that the smallest is the reciprocal of the largest in this case. Do you suppose that this somehow generalises?

Comment: Indeed, it's easy to see that $X_n$ has eigenvectors $e_i - e_{i+1}$ for eigenvalue $1$ for $i = 2 .. n-1$, so $1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-2$.  The determinant being $(-1)^{n+1}$ and trace being $1$ determines the other two eigenvalues.  Since this is a hermitian matrix, the singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues, and the smallest is the reciprocal of the largest.

Comment: That's a helpful observation, and good to have confirmed. However, I was considering how in this extreme case, where we are making the largest singular value essentially as large as possible, we have $s_n \in \Omega(1/n)$ --- specifically in this case because $s_n = 1/s_1$ for $s_1 = \sqrt{n^2 - O(n)}$. What I wonder is whether it is plausible this feature of this case generalises, allowing us to see that $s_n \in \Omega(1/n)$, or possibly $s_n \in \Omega(1/n^{1+c})$ for some particular small constant $c$?